# Building m3u8 playlist with mp4 files

Tags: http-live-streaming, playlist, m3u8, iptv

I own a digital receiver which could also play IPTV channels (m3u8). I want to build my own local IPTV station to be able to watch a video playlist on TV. I configured a computer as a web server. Now, I am trying to build the m3u8 playlist. I tried to add the video files (mp4) to a blank m3u8 file.

```
#EXTM3U
file1.mp4
file2.mp4
```

The problem is that my IPTV player only plays file1.mp4 then stops. I am new to hls, however I would like to avoid to convert all my videos to hls with ts segments.

Are there any ways to make it working? Thank you!

Comment: You *may* be able to get this to work with `EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY`.  Though, I'm curious what is generating these MP4 files.  Also note that you *can* use MP4/ISOBMFF with HLS these days, depending on what clients you need to support.

Answer (score 0):

While the first mp4 is recognized and played correctly, it isn't the 'correct' type of mp4 file to be played in this type of playlist.  They need to be encoded as '**Fragmented MPEG-4**' files. I'm suspecting that each file needs to contain a bit of information about the next segment.

From [RFC 8216](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8216#section-3.3):

> 3.3.  Fragmented MPEG-4
>
> MPEG-4 Fragments are specified by the ISO Base Media File Format
> [ISOBMFF].  Unlike regular MPEG-4 files that have a Movie Box
> ('moov') that contains sample tables and a Media Data Box ('mdat')
> containing the corresponding samples, an MPEG-4 Fragment consists of
> a Movie Fragment Box ('moof') containing a subset of the sample table
> and a Media Data Box containing those samples.  Use of MPEG-4
> Fragments does require a Movie Box for initialization, but that Movie
> Box contains only non-sample-specific information such as track and
> sample descriptions.
>
> A Fragmented MPEG-4 (fMP4) Segment is a "segment" as defined by
> Section 3 of [ISOBMFF], including the constraints on Media Data Boxes
> in Section 8.16 of [ISOBMFF].
>
> The Media Initialization Section for an fMP4 Segment is an ISO Base
> Media File that can initialize a parser for that Segment.
>
> Broadly speaking, fMP4 Segments and Media Initialization Sections
> are    [ISOBMFF] files that also satisfy the constraints described in
> this    section.
>
> The Media Initialization Section for an fMP4 Segment MUST contain a
> File Type Box ('ftyp') containing a brand that is compatible with
> 'iso6' or higher.  The File Type Box MUST be followed by a Movie Box.
> The Movie Box MUST contain a Track Box ('trak') for every Track
> Fragment Box ('traf') in the fMP4 Segment, with matching track_ID.
> Each Track Box SHOULD contain a sample table, but its sample count
> MUST be zero.  Movie Header Boxes ('mvhd') and Track Header Boxes
> ('tkhd') MUST have durations of zero.  A Movie Extends Box ('mvex')
> MUST follow the last Track Box.  Note that a Common Media Application
> Format (CMAF) Header [CMAF] meets all these requirements.